# Is Stack Overflow Teams always free for first 25 teammates, even after the 14 day trial?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, pricing

Stack Overflow Teams pricing page mentions that it is "Free for the first 25 teammates" but it also mentions "Free 14 day trial"

Does this mean that after 14 days each user (including the first 25) will cost $5pcm (per calendar month)?

Or that it's free for up to 25 users indefinitely, and only 26th member onwards cost money at $5pcm each, with the first 14 days being free?

Or maybe something different?

[image: SO Teams pricing]

Comment: The proposed duplicate is very similar, but the answer there mentioned that it was " a special promotion running only for the month of September."  This is a different situation, which _could_ have different rules (one noticeable one being 25 vs 10 free teammates).  I'd think this question should stay open as a non-duplicate.

Comment: Even if the number changed, the situation is the same. After the first 14 days, you pay only for users above X.

Comment: The rules for the first 25 free are exactly the same as the first 10 free promotion, just with 25 instead of 10. As an aside, the first 25 free promotion is ending very soon.

Comment: @animuson I have to say that for existing accounts it's a bit confusing. I know I opened my Teams account when the promotion was "10 users", but I can't see anywhere in my account how many "free" users we are entitled to. I have a acquaintance that opened their account earlier and can't remember if when they opened their account it said "10" or "25". They currently have close to 10 users, and can't find that information in their account either. How does that work?

Comment: After recent events, how can you trust  "them" to keep offering the free users long term even when they say they will?   Likewise with not closing down stackoverflow for teams of it does not keep the in investors happy?

Comment: The 25 user-promotion has ended on the 14th, it's not available on the page anymore. While [the related announcement](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/14/were-making-it-easier-to-try-stack-overflow-for-teams/) goes on and on about how great it is that the signup is "easier" now, the fact that the free offering for small teams is gone was only acknowledged in the comments. For existing users, "that plan/offer will run for the foreseeable future".

Comment: I was actually planning to start using teams on the basis that the first 25 users were free and then expanding from there after showing management it worked. Now you have to pay from >=2 users, and obtain the ROI in 30 days - don't think I'll be rushing in any more - meh.